# Hiding the navigation bar in a background service- android

Tags: android-studio, navigationbar

I have an app that introduces a translucent view over all other running apps (basically a filter running as a background service). The problem that i am facing is that the app does not apply the filter over the navigation bar (bottom bar with back, home and recent tabs buttons).

The flags that i have used to create a view are shown in the code below:

```
 WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                0 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(mView, params);
```

Is there any special flag or anything else that i need to cover the nav bar ?

[This is the screenshot of the filter running with everything else covered except the nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYq3q.jpg)

Comment: http://room-15.github.io/blog/2015/03/17/overlaying-the-system-navigation-bar/ check this link may help you

Comment: I referred this link, but to no use.
The flag FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, also does not overlay the view over the navigation bar.
I am testing my app for android M.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN read full documentation

Answer (score 0):

Add a Y offset to your layoutparams for your overlay to go over your navigation bar.

```
 WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0, navbarHeight(),
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                0 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(mView, params);

private int navbarHeight() {
...code to calculate height of navbar
}
```